# How to use DuplicateRecordSet field: SobjectType

Tags: duplicate-management, schema

According to the documentation, DuplicateRecordSet there is a field **SobjectType**, however, after running the following code in Execute Anonymous, it doesn't appear that this field exists...

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mapObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> drsFields = mapObjects.get('duplicateRecordSet').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for(String k : drsFields.keySet()){
    System.debug(drsFields.get(k));
}
```

### Screenshot of output

[image]

Comment: What documentation are you referring to? The Object Reference page has no (more) mention of the field. I also cannot find it in any older versions of this document. 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterecordset.htm